# sqlalchemy multiple foreignkey

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In SQLAlchemy, I would like to write a set of records in table A.  Then in table B I want to write a record that references an (a priori) unknown number of the records in A.

In python terms, I would create classes A and B and then have a list in B that contains objects of type A.

Can that be done?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really a SQLAlchemy question, but a basic relational tables question.

You are either talking about a one-to-many relationship, or a many-to-many relationship, both of which SQLAlchemy supports out-of-the-box.

## One-to-many

A one-to-many relationship is one of basic containment; a department has many employees, but each employee has only one department. The class with only one outgoing relationship gets the foreign key in this case, so employees refer to departments, not the other way around.

The [example from the SQLAlchemy documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/relationships.html#one-to-many) is given as:

> ```
> class Parent(Base):
>     __tablename__ = 'parent'
>     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
>     children = relationship("Child")
>
> class Child(Base):
>     __tablename__ = 'child'
>     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
>     parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'))
> ```

So if your `A` classes can only be part of one `B` set, use this pattern.

## Many-to-many

A many-to-many relationship is one where both sides can refer to more than one instance of the other side. Think of employees and projects; an employee can be part of multiple projects, and a project can involve multiple employees.

In SQL, this kind of relationship requires an association table, an extra database table that holds the mapping between the two linked types. The [SQLAlchemy documentation on many-to-many relationships](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/relationships.html#many-to-many) documents clearly how to do this; here is the example:

> ```
> association_table = Table('association', Base.metadata,
>     Column('left_id', Integer, ForeignKey('left.id')),
>     Column('right_id', Integer, ForeignKey('right.id'))
> )
>
> class Parent(Base):
>     __tablename__ = 'left'
>     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
>     children = relationship("Child",
>                     secondary=association_table)
>
> class Child(Base):
>     __tablename__ = 'right'
>     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
> ```

Use this pattern if each `A` object can be part of more than one `B` set.

Comment: I actually read this before posting the question but I went back and read it again.  I still do not understand how this will work.  This association_table lets me have MANY 1 to 1 relationships, which when you look at them in aggregate is one kind of many-to-many I guess.  But not the kind that I want (which is a variable length list of ForeignKeys from Child to Parent.  I suppose I could just store the IDs in a binary blob...

Comment: @AndrewStone: That's how relational normalisation works. The extra table stores the variable length foreign keys for you. Search for 'many-to-many' and 'sql' and read up on the concept; this is not limited to SQLAlchemy alone.

Comment: @AndrewStone: Look at it this way: if you were to query the association table for all relationships where `TypeB_id="foobar"`, you'd get a limited list of rows, each one which is an id for a TypeA item, of variable length. That's how databases can store such relationships efficiently.

Comment: I think I am understanding... the "container" (the list) is not stored explicitly.  It is derived at the time of the query because I have what is essentially a bag of objects with a list identifier field (TypeB_id), and I select all items out of the bag that are members of a particular list (in this case have a particular TypeB id).  It seems to me that this architecture would support very efficient insert/delete and modifications.  But not so efficient for queries, am I right about that?

Comment: @AndrewStone: The database can optimize such joins; an index could help there (on the `TypeB_id` column if you mostly look from Type B to A, for example), but leave that work to the database, that's what it is good at. The query performance will be more than fine, much better in fact than if you hacked together your own variable-length reference field.